How do I sync board columns across teams in Azure DevOps?
I have 3 Teams in Azure DevOps under the same project. Team A has all the items in the backlog. Team Web has just the web items, and Team Mobile has mobile development.
When I move items across either the Web or Mobile team board, it does not update the Team A board. I would like it to also update the Team A board. The boards are identical with the exception of what Work Items are on that board.
Is there a fix for this or an alternative work around?
